# The quickest way to write two dictionaries within each other into a MySQL table with Python?

Tags: python, mysql, insert

I have a the below dictionary format:

```
{ File1:{name1:2,name2:4},
  File2:{name3:3, name2:5},
  File3:{name5:6}  }
```

I want to insert them in a MySQL table with the below format:

```
Id|File_name|Name|#of Seen
1   File1    name1  2
2   File1    name2  4
3   File3    name3  3
4   File2    name2  5
5   File3    name5  6
```

I wrote the below code but I keep getting "null" in my table row(S)(it is only one row now).

```
connect = MySQLdb.connect(host = "127.8.2.3", port=3377, user = "root",  db="info")
with connect: 

    cur = connect.cursor()
    for i in maindict.items():
        keys=i[0]
        for k,v in innerdict.items():
            k=i[1]
            v=i[2]



            query="INSERT INTO TABLE names_info (id,filename,name) VALUES (%(id)s,% (filename)s, %(name)s)"
            cursor.execute(query)
```

Does anyone know why it is not working or how can I get the above table from my data?

Answer (score 1):

Well, a simple way to do the dictionary iteration would be...

```
maindict = {'File1': {'name1': 2, 'name2': 4},
            'File2': {'name3': 3, 'name2': 5},
            'File3': {'name5': 6}}

for filename, name_and_number in maindict.iteritems():
    for name, number in name_and_number.iteritems():
        print filename, name, number
```

...and you should probably replace these lines...

```
query="INSERT INTO TABLE names_info (id,filename,name) VALUES (%(id)s,% (filename)s, %(name)s)"
cursor.execute(query)
```

...with something more like this...

```
query = "INSERT INTO TABLE names_info (id,filename,name) VALUES (%s,%s,%s)"
cursor.execute(query, [id, filename, name])
```

...to avoid any potential [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) issues.

Comment: I have tried your code now I get no error but still no row is displayed in my SQL table.there is only one row.Do you know why?

Comment: @user2058811 Not really. If it's a different problem then open a new question, ensuring you quote the relevant parts of your code verbatim. Looks like there was a large chunk missing from the one in this question.